# Monte Carlo Integration - Measurability of the function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, monte-carlo

The below question is from Durrett's book on Probability theory. I wanted to ask why we need $f$ to be a measurable function fo part (i) of the question. My proof is as follows:

Since $ U_i $ are i.i.d, so are their functions. Now, $ \mathbb{E}f(U_i) = I$, and $\mathbb{E}|f(U_i)| = \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx < \infty$ by assumption, we have by the weak law of large numbers that $I_n \rightarrow I$ in probability.

[image]

Comment: if $f$ is not measurable then you can't define the integral, i.e., expressions like $\int f$ just make sense for measurable functions

Comment: Right, that's what I thought too but wasn't sure why one couldn't just say $f$ should be integrable rather than measurable and integrable.

Comment: yes, its unfortunate the wording, it would be enough to say that $f$ is integrable (in the probability space $([0,1],\lambda )$)